# How to persist views for ADO.NET EDM when database is recreated

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, ef-code-first

I am working on a project that started with code-first POCO objects representing database structure. For development purposes we use *drop and create* when database is changed.

There is a new requirement for providing support for OData queryable endpoints. So I created new ADO.NET Entity Data model (generated from existing database).

I would like to use EDM only for retrieving data from **database views**.
But as far as I understand there is no way how to specify them "in code" so they would be persisted in the EDM. And if I create a view in the database, regenerate EDM and then change the code-first structure, the DB is regenerated and view is gone.

This is a problem only for development phase but a big one.

Only solution to this problem I can think of is to keep a SQL definition of all views and execute them when Entity Framework is creating the database.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code first approach does not support creating Views. So you have to look for other options. I would suggest creating migrations (auto upgrade works in most cases) and avoid using drop/create method. This would preserve Views and keep all the benefits of code first.